# Exception: Could not load file or Assembly XXXX or one of it's dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, static-libraries

I have a C# solution with 3 C# .Net framework 4.7.2 projects of which a simple Class Library, a Windows Forms Control library and a Windows Forms test application. I've created a control which calls a static function in a public class "ColorHelper" for retrieving a secondary blended color based on the fore color of the control. This works fine in both designer and runtime, when this function is in the same project as the control, but throws this exception when placed in the third project, i.e. the Class Library. I've referenced this 3r project and also included the using statement. Syntax seems Ok, no errors on compiling, however when I want to place the control on a test form, the exception is thrown.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ASD.Drawing.Helpers
{
    public class ColorHelper : object
    {

        public static double BlendColor(double foreColor, double backColor, double alpha)
        {
            return Math.Min(Math.Max(backColor + alpha * (foreColor - backColor), 0.0D), 255.0D);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adjust the color by lighten or darken the color
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="color">The base color</param>
        /// <param name="gradientPercentage">The percentage of gradient. Negative to darken the color and negative to lighten the color.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Color GradientColor(Color color, int gradientPercentage)
        {
            if (gradientPercentage == 100) return color;

            //if positive then blend with white else blend with black
            float backColor = gradientPercentage > 0 ? 255.0F : 0.0F;

            // 0 = transparent foreColor; 1 = opaque foreColor
            double alpha = 1.0F - Math.Abs(Math.Max(Math.Min(gradientPercentage, 100), -100)) / 100.0;

            byte r = (byte)BlendColor(color.R, backColor, alpha);
            byte g = (byte)BlendColor(color.G, backColor, alpha);
            byte b = (byte)BlendColor(color.B, backColor, alpha);

            return Color.FromArgb(color.A, r, g, b);
        }
    };
}
```

The function is called from the Windows Forms Control Library

```
using ASD.Drawing.Helpers;
using ASD.Forms.Controls;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace ASD.Forms.Renderers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for the button renderers
    /// </summary>
    public class ButtonRenderer : BaseRenderer
    {
        ...

        /// <summary>
        /// Draw the body of the control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Gr"></param>
        /// <param name="rc"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual bool DrawBody(Graphics Gr, RectangleF rc)
        {
            if (Button == null)
                return false;

            Color bodyColor = Button.ButtonColor;
            Color cDark = ColorHelper.GradientColor(bodyColor, -80);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

It has been a really long while since I've been programming (approx. 5 years) I've forgotten a lot and I'm really at a loss here. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: For the moment I've moved the ColorHelper back into the Windows Forms Control Library project, but forgot to remove the project's reference to the ASD.Drawing project (Class Library) and the same exception is thrown. However when I remove the project's reference it works fine again in t both the desgner and runtime. How is it possible that I cannot reference another project in thsi project?

Comment: Where are you instantiating your ColorHelper? It looks like you're using it like it's a static class

Comment: Try it:  var colorHelper = new ColorHelper(); Color cDark = colorHelper .GradientColor(bodyColor, -80);

Comment: I'ts not instantiated and indeed used as a static class. But I think the problem is in my project referencing other projects in the solution. I'm trying to refactor a custom control to use in a form. So the control will be configured in the designer and needs to show accordingly. I'm always open for suggestions and enhancements, because a lot of the stuff has been vanished from my brains.

Comment: Do you have this code in a git repository?

Comment: Hello Augusto, I've tried that already, and that didn't do the trick. I've did some cleaning and rebuilding and have now the situation that the ColorHelper Class is in both projects under different namespaces. When I reference the ColorHelper class in the same project ASD.Drawing everything works fine both in designer (when I place the control on the form) and runtime. However when I switch the reference to the ColorHelper in the other project (and namespace) ASD.Drawing the exception is thrown. Hope this bit of information is helpfull!?

Comment: No, I use TFS, or Azure DevOps nowadays.

Comment: If this method works in the form project and does not work in the class library then some reference that exists in your Form and not exists in your class library. Without access to the complete code, I am not sure what

Comment: By the way, System.Drawing is a Windows Form assembly and it's not added by default. You need to manually add the reference. But from what you said, did you do it right? You may need to add another reference manually.

Comment: I've added my code to Github under https://github.com/Willunsnix/ASD-Root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your reference to ASD.Forms in the ASD.Forms.UITest project is corrupted. Remove it, compile the ASD.Forms and ASD.Drawing projects and again add the ASD.Forms reference to ASD.Forms.UITest, then make sure that the ASD.Forms.UITest project is set as a startup project (right click in the project > set as startUp project) why startup projects must have a startup file (an .exe for example). After that, it should work normally:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Augusto. I've cleaned and rebuild the solution several times but it never worked. Now I followed your exact steps and it works.